# CoreOS Cluster DNS setup

Tags: coreos

There is a coreos cluster of 3 units - 2 web servers and an nginx load balancer - each residing on its own digital ocean instance. How do I set up dns in such way that it always points to the load balancer instance given that it may end up on any of the machines?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Largely that will depend on your DNS infrastructure.  Using [TSIG](https://sort.symantec.com/public/documents/vcs/6.0/linux/productguides/html/vcs_bundled_agents/ch03s06s06s06.htm) with the [nsupdate](http://agiletesting.blogspot.com/2012/03/dynamic-dns-updates-with-nsupdate-and.html) client is going to be your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to take the load balancer(s) out of the cluster and using sidekick units to announce the various services' IP to the load balancer. That way your load balancers have static IP's which are easier to manage from a DNS standpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MachineID` option of fleet and always run load balancer on a specific CoreOS

Reference: https://coreos.com/docs/launching-containers/launching/fleet-unit-files/

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to start nginx on all my coreos servers. This way I get rid of the "this machine does that" thing and I don't care where my services are running, and if something goes wrong I just add or remove a machine to the cluster.

Nginx being super light, that's not an issue.